# Firebase dynamic deep link arrives nil after install

Tags: ios, firebase, deep-linking, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am attempting to use Firebase to pass deep links into my app that survive install.

To test this I am following the steps provided by the Firebase documentation and Firecast video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFPo296OQqk) at about the 12min 40s mark. The steps are as follows:

1. First I delete the app from my device.
2. Then I press the link to open the app store.
3. Then I run my app from xcode.
4. Expected: The dynamicLink.url property will be equal to "https: //www.example.com/data/helloworld" in application:openURL
5. Reality: The dynamicLink.url property arrives nil.

This is the deeplink url that I created in the Firebase console: https://nqze6app.goo.gl/RIl8

This is the url that is passed into application:openURL prior to being passed into  dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL : com.johnbogil.voices://google/link/dismiss?fdl_cookie

This is the code in my openURL call:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options { 
  FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];
  if (dynamicLink) { 
    NSLog(@"I am handling a link through the openURL method"); 
    [self handleDynamicLink:dynamicLink]; 
    return YES; 
  } else { 
    return NO; 
  } 
}
```

Not sure why dynamicLink.url is arriving nil. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Can you also share... 1. The content of your `application:openURL` call? and 2. The fully expanded dynamic link? (In the Firebase control panel, click on "Link details" in the overflow menu and you should see it below.)

Comment: @ToddKerpelman
 
1) ` - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks]dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];
    if (dynamicLink) {
        NSLog(@"I am handling a link through the openURL method");
        [self handleDynamicLink:dynamicLink];
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}`

2) https://nqze6.app.goo.gl/?link=https://www.example.com/data/helloworld&isi=965692648&ibi=com.johnbogil.voices

Targeting and testing for iOS 9.3

Comment: Okay. So can you confirm that you're seeing the "I am handling a link through the openURL method" link in your console output? Also... is there a chance you have Safari in "Private" mode?

Comment: @ToddKerpelman I was using Safari in private mode. Leaving private mode solved the issue :)

Comment: Woo hoo! I went ahead and posted this as the official answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anybody who else who's encountering this same error...

1. If your `application:openURL` method is getting called, and
2. You do seem to be getting a valid `dynamicLink` object from your `dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL` method, but
3. The `url` parameter of that dynamicLink object is nil

Then double-check to see if you're in "Private" mode in Safari. That will kinda mess with Firebase Dynamic Links' ability to retrieve the original link that you clicked on.

Comment: I tried all but am still getting FIRDynamicLink and error both as nil

Comment: can you help with this too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42093902/6144372

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I was getting callback of **restorationHandler** but in **handleUniversalLink** callback **dynamiclink** and error both were nil. After spending some time I found my issue.

Turns out, url is case sensitive. For example if your url is:

**https://xzz6b.app.goo.gl/0EWv**

and you wrote **https://xzz6b.app.goo.gl/0ewv** in notes and clicked it. It will load your app and even give you callback of **restorationHandler** but **dynamiclink** will be nil.

You can try it even in browser.

Hope it helps anybody.

Comment: yeah. Also an extra character in the end will give same effect, like https://xzz6b.app.goo.gl/0EWv'

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was due to the fact that I was using custom domains and I missed the bit in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app) (see point #3) that explicitly states that you need to list your Dynamic Links URL prefixes using a key called `FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains` in your `Info.plist` file.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem.

### Solution:

From [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive)

> If the Dynamic Link isn't found on your app's first launch (on any
>   version of iOS), this method will be called with the FIRDynamicLink's
>   url set to nil, indicating that the SDK failed to find a matching
>   pending Dynamic Link.

So you have to check this step

> In the Info tab of your app's Xcode project, create a new URL type to
>   be used for Dynamic Links. Set the Identifier field to a unique value
>   and the URL scheme field to be your bundle identifier, which is the
>   default URL scheme used by Dynamic Links.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update Firebase/DynamicLinks. 
I'd had the same issue and then I run pod update Firebase/DynamicLinks. 
Now pod Firebase/DynamicLinks is 6.21.0 version and DynamicLink object has correct url value.