# Why full/long dynamic link is not getting retrieved/received?

Tags: android, firebase, intentfilter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm creating a deep/dynamic link following this [github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/dynamiclinks) project.

Here's the link which is getting created: `https://appcode.app.goo.gl/?link=http://example.com/-example&apn=com.abc.xxx&amv=16&ad=0&extraParameter=null`

This is the method I'm using for sharing it:

```
private void shareDeepLink(String deepLink) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Firebase Deep Link");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, deepLink);

            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is the `intent-filters` defined in my app's `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

      <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http"/>
      <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

This is how I'm trying to receive the shared `deep-link`:

```
boolean autoLaunchDeepLink = false;
        AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, autoLaunchDeepLink)
                .setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(@NonNull AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
                                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    // Extract deep link from Intent
                                    Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
                                    final String deepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);
                                    Log.d("deepLinkMainActivity", deepLink);

                                } else {
                                    Log.d("getInvitation", "getInvitation: no deep link found.");
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Here's what is getting logged out (received deep-link): `http://example.com/-example`

As you can clearly see, I'm not getting the exact deep-link which was created and instead I'm getting it's altered version. Why?

**And how can I** get exactly the same deep-link which was created and shared?

Comment: Do you mean that the line 'Log.d("deepLinkMainActivity", deepLink);' outputs 'http://example.com/-example'? I think that is exactly what you should expect with a link that you provided. Can you please tell what do you expect to see?

Comment: Your intent filter defines scheme "https", but you use "http" in your link. That is one thing that could cause problems.

Comment: @diidu I expect to see this whole thing: `https://appcode.app.goo.gl/?link=http://example.com/-example&apn=com.abc.xxx&amv=16&ad=0&extraParameter=null`

Comment: That is not the purpose. In the original url you can even give different url to be given to browser and to the app with &al= and you can also provide fallback link.

Comment: @diidu I want to add extra query parameters and then retrieve them later when the link is received. How to?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You are reciving the deeplink properly

This is the complete link generated that contains info like the apn : the package name of your app, the information to know for example which app need to be opened

https://appcode.app.goo.gl/?link=http://example.com/-example&apn=com.abc.xxx&amv=16&ad=0&extraParameter=null

This is your deeplink
link=http://example.com/-example. So, if you want to add more parameters you can do it  here, like in the example bellow

link=http://example.com/-example&blabla.

So you have this as result https://appcode.app.goo.gl/?link=http://example.com/-example&blabla&apn=com.abc.xxx&amv=16&ad=0

If you want this portion can be encoded  http://example.com/-example&blabla

You can try this and let me know.

You can refer this info here https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android

Comment: I have added more parameters as told by you, now how can I retrieve them when I receive the link?

Comment: Did you see the extra parameters in the deeplink when call `AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation` if true, so can use a parse to get the parameters, maybe and split of "&". Right now i dont have an example because right now i am using Branchio.

Comment: I'm unable to understand what you said here.. ^

Comment: I have explained the problem much clearly here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42119692/6144372 Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<data
       android:host="xxx.abc.com"
       android:scheme="https"/>
```

with

```
<data
       android:host="example.com"
       android:scheme="http"/>
```

Comment: There is no issues on use http or https

Comment: then there must be issue of host name

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. The issue was the link which I'm receiving is "Long link".
We can create two types of links from firebase:

1. Short Link
   https://appcode.app.goo.gl/?email=abc@gmail.com
2. Long Link
   https://appcode.app.goo.gl/?link=http://example.com/-example&apn=com.abc.xxx&amv=16&ad=0&extraParameter=null

So that's why I'm facing this issue.
I solved it by fetching the whole link from

```
 Uri uriData = intent.data
```

And to fetch particular query param from the link:

```
  String email = uriData.getQueryParameter("email")
```

I hope it will help anyone!!