# Sending data in dynamic link in firebase

Tags: firebase, deeplink

I have dynamic links enabled in my firebase console. I'm able to create links but not able to provide different data per dynamic link.

I checked a few questions here at stack overflow with the same doubt, but my doubt is still unclear. I checked out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093902/why-full-long-dynamic-link-is-not-getting-retrieved-received). As per the link provided, I'm able to create dynamic links using the query string pattern, but it keeps on getting the exact data as provided in the firebase console. For example,

my link is:

```
https://XXXX.XXXX.goo.gl/?link=http://deeplink.com/deeplink/ViewLocation?user_id%26user_group%26mentor_info%26distance&apn=com.XXXXX.app&afl=https://www.XXXXX.com/app/download&isi=1XXXX&ibi=com.XXXXXX.app&ifl=https://www.XXXXX.com/
```

Now the problem here is that we should be able to send different values to the parameters user_id, user_group, mentor_info etc. However, it returns the entire above deeplink without any parameters or different values. If I add default values to the parameters and set it in firebase console, it gives out the exact values in response to any different values we sent.

How should I integrate a structure in firebase so that I could send values to the parameters mentioned in the structure?